# Regex Match Part of Line, Then Look Behind and Replace (and also delete that line)

Tags: php, regex, pcre, lookbehind

I have a string with this format:

```
                $something = $gateway->execute($query) or die(mysql_error() . " here");
                $id  = mysql_insert_id();
```

This is tricky, because I want to end up with this:

```
$id = $gateway->execute($query) or die(mysql_error() . " here");
```

I've tried matching the mysql_insert_id line, then looking behind for $gateway->execute and replacing $something with the captured $id, but I coudln't figure it out. Is this even possible? 
I also want to delete the mysql_insert_id line, but I could always grep and replace afterwards and replace with empty string.

Thanks.

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can match botch elements and reassemble them as needed like that:

```
\$\w+\s+=\s+(\$gateway->execute\(\$query\)\s+or\s+die\(mysql_error\(\)\s+\.\s+"\s+here"\);).*(\$id)\s+=\s+mysql_insert_id\(\);
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GscJ2p/1)

This can be simplified if the $gateway->.. part is a fixed string.